# how to fill all empty cells using values of above cells using java

Tags: java, csv

csv looks like

```
state  name
IL     Mike 
       Sam
CA     Kate
       Bill
       Leah
```

Should be as follows

```
state  name
IL     Mike 
IL     Sam
CA     Kate
CA     Bill
CA     Leah
```

I am trying to do print it as shown above

```
PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\file.csv");
File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Book1.csv");
List<String> lines1 = Files.readAllLines(file1.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

for (String line : lines1) {
String[] array = line.split(",");
pw1.println(array[0]+","+array[1]);
}   
pw1.flush();
pw1.close();
```

how can i achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, save the previous state till it change

I think this is the way to do that.

```
String state = "";
int counter =0;
for (String line : lines1) {
     String[] array = line.split(",");
     if (array[0] != null && !array[0].isEmpty()){
            state = array[0];
            counter = 0;
     }
     else{
           counter++;
     }
     pw1.println(state+ counter +","+array[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanku Mzf. if i want to add a autoincrement number for the duplicate how can i add to the array

Comment: not sure that I understand what you want to count.... for each state you want to count the names?

Comment: As it is printing IL in the second row can we print the value as a count for duplicate
IL
IL1
CA
CA1
CA2
like this